# Plugin being triggered by every instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery and have built a small plugin.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.section').Section();
});



jQuery.fn.Section = function(func, options){

if(typeof(func)==='undefined') func = 'new';
if(typeof(options)==='undefined') options = new Object();


//var settings = $.extend({}, options);

var DOM = jQuery(this);
var p = DOM.parent();
var collapsed = false;
var slide_area = DOM.find('.slide_area');
var toggle_btn = DOM.find('.toggle_btn');

return this.each( function() {

    switch(func){

        case 'new':

            toggle_btn.on('click', function(){console.log('click');

                if (collapsed){

                    slide_area.slideDown();
                    toggle_btn.text('-');
                    collapsed = false;
                }else{

                    slide_area.slideUp();
                    toggle_btn.text('+');
                    collapsed = true;
                }
            });
        break;
    }



});
}
```

You can see, I am using a class selector to attach the Section plugin to all DIV's with the class 'section'.

In the Section plugin, there is a listener for a toggle button in the section.

The problem is that when I click on the toggle button, the event is fired 4 times.(There are 4 DIV's with a 'section' class.

I thought I had this plugin set-up correctly so it plays well with jQuery. I have looked around, but could not find what I've done incorrectly.

How can I change this so it does not trigger the click function once for each instance of a 'section' DIV?

Here is the HTML to help understand the structure:

```
<div class="section"><!-- paypal settings -->
    <h3>Paypal Settings</h3>

    <div class="section_controls">
        <div class="toggle_btn">-</div>
        <div class="hr" style="background-color: <?php echo $settings->secondary_color; ?>;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is suspicious: `var DOM = jQuery(this);` It suggests that you don't fully realize that `this` is already a jQuery object in plugins, not a raw DOM element (unlike `this` in event callbacks and such).

Comment: I did that to counter when the scope changes and 'this' means something more recent. It still gives me direct access to the main element. Is there a better way to do this? As you can probably tell, I am still pretty green at this stuff.

Comment: Simply `var DOM = this;` would handle that. But with a jQuery plugin, if you're doing **any** work outside the `this.each(...)` other than checking/massaging options, you should double-check that it really makes sense to do that, because remember that the plugin must operate on each element in the matched set *independently* (for the most part). For instance, later you do `var slide_area = DOM.find('.slide_area');` -- that means that `slide_area` is a set of **all** `.slide_area` elements in **all** elements in the set you were called on. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Okie. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your variables in the `return this.each` like this:

```
return this.each( function() {
var DOM = jQuery(this);
var p = DOM.parent();
var collapsed = false;
var slide_area = DOM.find('.slide_area');
var toggle_btn = DOM.find('.toggle_btn');

    switch(func){

        case 'new':

            toggle_btn.on('click', function(){
                console.log('click');

                if (collapsed){

                    slide_area.slideDown();
                    toggle_btn.text('-');
                    collapsed = false;
                }else{

                    slide_area.slideUp();
                    toggle_btn.text('+');
                    collapsed = true;
                }
            });
        break;
    }



});
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. That makes perfect sense. Thanks twain.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing work outside your `this.each(...)` that should be *inside* it. For instance, your lines:

```
var slide_area = DOM.find('.slide_area');
var toggle_btn = DOM.find('.toggle_btn');
```

Those are outside the `this.each(...)` part of your plugin, and you've set `DOM` to (effectively) the set of elements your plugin was called on. That means that `slide_area` refers to **all** `.slide_area` elements in **all** of the sections you were called with, and that `toggle_btn` refers to **all** `.toggle_btn` elements in **all** of the sections you were called with. Later in your `this.each(...)`, you hook up a handler using `toggle_btn.on(...)`, and so you hook it up to all four toggle buttons four separate times.

At first glance, everything you're doing outside your `this.each(...)` should be *inside* it.